# Load generator cannot establish expected number of outbound tcp/ip connections

Tags: windows, tcp, connection, loadrunner

We're trying to run lots of vusers (hundreds) against our application under test using truclient. However, the load generator (a windows 2008 r2 32GB -  ram  - 64 bit - 2 processors w/ 8 cores) isn't able to create more than 350 outbound tcp connections regardless of the number of vusers. CPU and memory on the generator is looking fine. The app under test is looking fine too.

What could and should be tuned on the load generator (potentially windows stuff) in order to open more connections and generate more traffic?

Answer (score 3):

You may find this useful

http://smallvoid.com/article/winnt-tcpip-max-limit.html

Keep in Mind that while you can replay virtual users on 64 bit hardware, the multi threaded driver is a 32 bit software component so you are going to be limited by any limit imposed on the WOW32 subsystem by Microsoft for maximum number of tcp sessions.   You are also going to have a limitation of a 32 bit address space for RAM

Comment: +1 cause this should really be common knowledge. I learnt by getting burned by this one.